# postfix multiple alias with response (from alias mail)

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have a postfix - dovecot mail server installed over a Ubuntu 14.04 VPS.

Is the following situation possible? I have tried using alias, but when i try to reply the mail, this one is delivered from bob1@domain.com (and this mail should be hidden!)

Mail sent to info@domain.com, this mail delivers to bob1@domain.com and to bob2@domain.com. When bob1 or bob2 replys the mail, it should be sent from info@domain.com. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: (1) If you want *ALL** email sent by bob1@ and bob2@ appears from info@, then go through [sebokopter answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/707515/postfix-multiple-alias-with-response-from-alias-mail/707779#707779) below. (2) For other scenario, see this QA: [Postfix reply to emails addressed to external email while keeping the correct from address](http://serverfault.com/questions/649182/postfix-reply-to-emails-addressed-to-external-email-while-keeping-the-correct-fr/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to set [sender_canonical_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_canonical_maps) for outgoing mails. This way you get both header and envolope addresses rewritten.

But for incoming mails [recipient_canonical_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_canonical_maps) doesn't work since you can only map to one E-Mail address. Anyways it's probably cleaner to have [recipient_bcc_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_bcc_maps) (delivers to info, bob1 and bob2) or [virtual_alias_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps) (delivers to bob1 and bob2 instead of info).

So you should use something like this:

/etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias_maps
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
```

/etc/postfix/sender_canonical:

```
bob1@domain.com info@domain.com
bob2@domain.com info@domain.com
```

/etc/postfix/virtual_alias_maps:

```
info@domain.com bob1@domain.com, bob2@domain.com
```

You maybe have to add domain.com in the virtual_alias_maps table if it is not already defined as one of Postfix destionation domains somewhere in your configuration.

Please have a look at Postfix' [address rewriting README](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html) for more details.

PS: Your described behaviour sounds like an [Issue Tracking System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Issue_tracking_system), so you may want to have a look at one of those systems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue-tracking_systems